# Is it possible to install multi-user mode of visual studio code in a server?

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I need to set up a computational server for my lab team, mainly for julia development.

I already set up the server with JupyterHub, but while Jupyter is great for teaching, I prefer the classical development environments for everyday programming.

I know you can connect Juno with external services, but it's not for everyone, especially for my colleagues in windows.

So.. it's a pity that it doesn't exist a "junoServer" like RServer.
I wander if instead VSCode (that has a Julia plugin) can be installed in multi-user mode as RServer or JupiterHub.

Comment: You could use the [Windows 10 OpenSSH](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/12/15/using-the-openssh-beta-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update-and-windows-server-1709/) or [Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/) (if you need graphics) combined with an [sftp plugin for vscode](https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp) to edit remote files, then ssh in from the terminal in VS Code. Never tried it myself, but in theory it should work?

Comment: @IanMarshall do you mean x-tunnelling trough SSH ? Yes, that would be possible, I use it to provide other desktop apps like qgis (my windows collegues use in that case [mobaxterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download.html)), but a native server would be much more simpler.